problem with opening app after installing http dependencie on flutter
im new on flutter and im working on an app that needs to make rest api calls using firebase, i was able to open the app on my emulator (pixel 7 phone) and on my chrome browser before installing the http dependencie but after installing it i can only open in my phone emulator, when i try opening it on chrome the following errors apear:
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:412:12: Error: The method 'handleThenable' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.

'DocumentReference' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'handleThenable'.
return handleThenable(callMethod(firestore_interop.updateDoc, 'apply', [
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:412:27: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
'DocumentReference' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return handleThenable(callMethod(firestore_interop.updateDoc, 'apply', [
^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:544:12: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class 'Query'.
'Query' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(method, 'apply', [null, jsify(args)]);
^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:569:14: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class 'Query'.
'Query' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(firestore_interop.or, 'apply', [null, jsFilters]);
^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:571:14: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class 'Query'.
'Query' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(firestore_interop.and, 'apply', [null, jsFilters]);
^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:798:12: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class '_Updatable'.
'_Updatable' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(jsObject, 'update', args);
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:830:12: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class '_FieldValueArrayUnion'.
'_FieldValueArrayUnion' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(
^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:844:12: Error: The method 'callMethod' isn't defined for the class '_FieldValueArrayRemove'.
'_FieldValueArrayRemove' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.10.8/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'callMethod'.
return callMethod(

i tried to open the flutter app using chrome and got errors

Did you try doing a flutter pub get in the terminal? Perhaps it needs to save the package version in the pubspec.lock lockfile. Hitting save while on your pubspec.yaml file also has the same effect.

Yes, i even tried to flutter clean and flutter pub get again and same issue

Hmm, and you have the cloud_firestore package as a dependency correct?

Yes, i followed the same steps that where in the official documentation

I'm looking at the errors and it seems that you might have an older version of the package. Can you update it to 3.12.2 if it is not already?

exactly what package do i update?

I found the package and updated and it worked, thank you so much
